# Cannot change consistency using "goapp test"

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Google's AppEngine service provides an eventually consistent database for storage of application data in production.  For testing, Google provides a similar database that emulates the consistency characteristics of the production database.  Testing requirements may vary so Google supplies command line parameters to their test server, `dev_appserver.py`, that modify the consistency characteristics as needed for testing.

I am using the `goapp` tools to run our automated test environment for my AppEngine development.  `goapp test` is responsible for running our automated server API tests.  `goapp test` does not appear to have a way of setting the datastore's consistency level via the command line parameters, unlike `dev_appserver.py`, even though `goapp test` launches `dev_appserver.py` at some point during the testing process.

Is there a way to pass command line parameters to `dev_appserver.py` from `goapp test`?  If not, is there an alternative method for setting the consistency from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using the [aetest package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/#Go_Introducing_the_aetest_package).
If this is the case you should set the [StronglyConsistentDatastore member of the `aetest.Options` struct](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/reference#Options) accordingly.

Here is an example:

**hello.go**

```
package hello

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "appengine"
    datastore "appengine/datastore"
)

type Employee struct {
        FirstName          string
        LastName           string
        HireDate           time.Time
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

    q := datastore.NewQuery("Employee").Filter("FirstName =", "Antonio")

    var people []Employee

    if _, err := q.GetAll(ctx, &people); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Matches %v", len(people))
}
```

**hello_test.go**

```
package hello

import (
    "time"
    "testing"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "appengine"
    "appengine/aetest"
    datastore "appengine/datastore"
)

const consistency_strong = true; // set to false and the test will fail

func TestMyHandler(t *testing.T) {
    options := &aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: consistency_strong}
    inst, err := aetest.NewInstance(options)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to create instance: %v", err)
    }
    defer inst.Close()

    req, err := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to create req1: %v", err)
    }
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)

    employee := &Employee{
            FirstName: "Antonio",
            LastName:  "Salieri",
            HireDate:  time.Now(),
    }

    key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Employee", nil)

    _, err = datastore.Put(ctx, key, employee)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error setting test data: %v", err)
    }

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    handler(w, req)

    if w.Body.String() != "Matches 1" {
        t.Fatalf("Expected 1 record got %v", w.Body)
    }
}
```

As you have mentioned the go tools merely wrap dev_appserver.py. This means that if you are not using `aetest` you can always run your app with a chosen consistency policy like so:

`/usr/local/go_appengine/dev_appserver.py --datastore_consistency_policy consistent .`

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way, possibly undocumented, to set the consistency from `goapp` command line without resorting to starting a new instance in code.  Your answer implies that there isn't a way, or at least you are unaware of a way to do this.  Is there an alternate way to achieve the same ends from the `goapp` command line?